# How to check Auth status in Laravel Passport?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-passport

I am trying to check user authentication status in Laravel with Passport auth. Here is what I am trying:

#### api.php

```
Route::post('/check-auth-status', 'LoginController@checkUserAuthStatus')->middleware('auth:api');
```

#### LoginController

```
public function checkUserAuthStatus(Request $request)
{
  if($request->user() !== auth()->user())
  return response()->json('Unauthorized user',401);
}
```

Here the problem is the url does not hit when the user is logged out because of the `middleware('auth:api')` in route, so it's send an unauthorized message to the app.
Moreever, Auth::check() does not work(always returns false).

What to do here ? Or any better idea ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like your code it will not work as you appled middleware so if not auth it will not go inside `checkUserAuthStatus` it will redirect to login page

you need to handel this from `Handler.php`

add this function to `Handler.php`

```php
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;


protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return $request->expectsJson()
        ? response()->json('Unauthorized user',401)
        : redirect('/login');
}
```

here `$request->expectsJson()` means if request `header` have `accept:application/json` then it will return json response with your custom message `Unauthorized user`

Comment: is that all ? Do i need to keep anyting in api.php or controller ?

Comment: no it will be global api `AuthenticationException` handler

Comment: ```return $request->expectsJson()? response()->json(['Unauthorized user'], 401 : response()->json(['Authorized user'], 201);```
it's returning 404 not found to the app.

Comment: 404 means your url is not present in your application and this code for handel `AuthenticationException`

Comment: as you said I removed the route from api.php & only kept the function on Handler.php !

Comment: no just add this code in `Handler.php` and check passport `unauth` error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228723/discussion-between-osman-rafi-and-kamlesh-paul).